# Undefined index on $_REQUEST

Tags: php, forms, request

I'm trying to make an update form for the records in my DB. This is the form:

```
<form id="form_update_ad" method="post" action="inc/API.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="input_publisher" id="input_publisher_edt" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="input_link" id="input_link_edt" placeholder="Link" />
    <input type="file" name="file2Upload_edt" id="file2Upload_edt" />
    <input type="submit" value="" id="btnUpdate" />
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="update_ad" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="curr_image_filename" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="curr_add_id" />
</form>
```

The values of all the input fields (except for 'file') are set with jQuery, and they're all set correctly, I double checked.

Then I have this jQuery function that is being executed once I hit the submit button:

```
$("#form_update_ad").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // some validations...
    if(errors.length==0)
    {
        $(this).off("submit");
        this.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        // if there are errors - do something here
    }
});
```

What I want to do in the API.php file is this: check if a new image file is being uploaded, if not - set new_image_filename to the current filename (request it from the `curr_image_filename` hidden input field), and if yes - delete the currently set file from the server, upload the new image, set new_image_filename to its name and update the DB. So I wrote this code:

```
$newImageFileName = "";
if($_FILES["file2Upload_edt"]["name"]=='')
{
    $newImageFileName = $_REQUEST["curr_image_filename"];
}
else
{
    if(delete_file_from_server($_REQUEST["curr_image_filename"]))
    {
        $newImageFileName = saveImage2Server("file2Upload_edt");
        update_ad($_REQUEST["curr_ad_id"],$_REQUEST["input_publisher"], $newImageFileName, $_REQUEST["input_link"]);
    }
}
```

But I'm keep getting this error message: Undefined index: curr_image_filename in mypath\API.php on line 21, which is this: `$newImageFileName = $_REQUEST["curr_image_filename"];`

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id != name`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="curr_image_filename" />
                              ^^----must be "name" to be submitted as a form field
```

No name, no submission. And IDs do not count as names.

Comment: Thanks! I no longer have this `Undefined index` message! A also noticed I have another problem with the placement of the call to `update_ad()` function (the code doesn't reach it if there's no new file to upload), so I changed it. Now I have some problems with my PDO Update query, will have to look into it. Again, thank you for your help!